# Simulate keypress as keydown and keyup

Tags: javascript

I build a game and have an issue.
My game looks for a few keydown which move the character.
I added an A* algorithm to let the players the option to move their character with a mouse click (It gives the keys for destination point).

My issue is:
The code is looking for keydown which allowing continuous click and the algorithm return the keys for destination point which should be keypress as per-key.

How should I simulate the keypress for this? (The main question is in AStarWalk function)

Code:

```
class Event {
constructor(engine) {
    this.engine = engine;
    this.engine.event = this;

    this.focus = false;

    this.pressedKeys = {};
    this.events = {};
    // - - - - - - - - - -
    // Events
    this.onKey('keydown', 'gameWindow', ['KeyA', 'ArrowLeft'], () => {
        this.engine.player.movePlayer(1);
    }); // Left
    this.onKey('keydown', 'gameWindow', ['KeyW', 'ArrowUp'], () => {
        this.engine.player.movePlayer(3);
    }); // Up
    this.onKey('keydown', 'gameWindow', ['KeyD', 'ArrowRight'], () => {
        this.engine.player.movePlayer(2);
    }); // Right
    this.onKey('keydown', 'gameWindow', ['KeyS', 'ArrowDown'], () => {
        this.engine.player.movePlayer(0);
    }); // Down
    this.onKey('keydown', 'gameWindow', ['KeyR'], () => {
        this.engine.player.running = true;
    }); // Start running
    this.onKey('keyup', 'gameWindow', ['KeyR'], () => {
        this.engine.player.running = false;
    }); // Stop running
    this.onKey('keyup', 'gameWindow', ['PrintScreen'], () => {
        console.log('save a picture');
    });
    this.onKey('focus', 'gameWindow', () => {
        this.focus = true;
    }); // On focus the game
    this.onKey('focusout', 'gameWindow', () => {
        this.focus = false;
        this.pressedKeys = {};
    }); // Focus has out from game
    this.onKey('mousedown','gameWindow', [0], (e) => {
        let x = Math.floor(e.layerX / this.engine.mapSettings.pxPerSquare);
        let y = Math.floor(e.layerY / this.engine.mapSettings.pxPerSquare);
        let node = [x, y];
        let path = this.engine.astar.findPath(node);
        this.AStarWalk(path);

    });
    // - - - - - - - - - -
    // addEventListener
    // code - for keyboard
    // botton - for mouse
    for (let id in this.events) {
        for (let type in this.events[id]) {
            if (!this.events[id].hasOwnProperty(type))
                continue;
            document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(type, (event) => {
                let e = event;
                if (this.inArray(type, ['keydown', 'keyup']))
                    event.preventDefault();
                // Define variables
                let key = e.code || e.button; // e.keyCode || e.which;
                // Check if the key has event
                if (!this.events[id][type].hasOwnProperty(key) && !this.events[id]['keyup'].hasOwnProperty(key))
                    return;
                // Check if the key already pressed
                if (this.pressedKeys.hasOwnProperty(key) && type === 'keydown')
                    return;
                // Do
                if (type === 'keydown')
                    this.pressedKeys[key] = e;
                else if (type === 'keyup') {
                    this.runCallbacks(this.events[id][type][key]);
                }
                else if (this.inArray(type, ['focus', 'focusout'])) {
                    for (let callback in this.events[id][type]) {
                        if (!this.events[id][type].hasOwnProperty(callback))
                            continue;
                        this.events[id][type][callback](e);
                    }
                }
                else if (this.inArray(type, ['mousedown', 'mouseup'])) {
                    this.runCallbacks(this.events[id][type][key], e);
                }
            });
            document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    }
    // - - - - - - - - - -
    // Thread
    this.engine.thread.thread(true, 0, (1000 / this.engine.graphic.lastfps), () => {
        for (let id in this.events) {
            for (let key in this.pressedKeys) {
                this.runCallbacks(this.events[id].keydown[key], key);
            }
        }
    });
}
runCallbacks(array, key) {
    let e;
    for (let callback in array) {
        if (!array.hasOwnProperty(callback))
            continue;
        e = (this.pressedKeys[key] instanceof Event) ? this.pressedKeys[key] : key;

        array[callback](e);
    }
}
inArray(key, array) {
    for (let i in array)
        if (array.hasOwnProperty(i) && array[i] === key)
            return true;
    return false;
}
onKey() {
    let event = arguments[0];
    let id = arguments[1];
    let keyCode = (this.inArray(event, ['keydown', 'keyup', 'mousedown', 'mouseup'])) ? arguments[2] : null;
    let callback = (!this.inArray(event, ['keydown', 'keyup', 'mousedown', 'mouseup'])) ? arguments[2] : arguments[3];
    // Convert keyCodeList to an array based on keyCode.
    if (keyCode != null) {
        if (!keyCode instanceof Array)
            keyCode = [keyCode];
    }
    // Create event id if is not exist.
    if (!this.events.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        this.events[id] = {
            keydown: {},
            keyup: {},
            focus: [],
            focusout: [],
            mousedown: {},
            mouseup: {}
        };
    }
    // Add event to an array
    if (keyCode !== null) {
        let done = false;
        for (let k in keyCode) {
            if (!keyCode.hasOwnProperty(k))
                continue;
            k = keyCode[k].toString();
            for (let key in this.events[id][event]) {
                if (key === k) {
                    if (callback !== undefined)
                        this.events[id][event][k].push(callback);
                    if (event === 'keydown')
                        this.events[id]['keyup'][k].push(() => { delete this.pressedKeys[k]; });
                    done = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!done) {
                if (callback !== undefined)
                    this.events[id][event][k] = [callback];
                if (event === 'keydown')
                    this.events[id]['keyup'][k] = [() => { delete this.pressedKeys[k]; }];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        this.events[id][event].push(callback);
    }
}
AStarGetKey(state) {
    if (state === 'LEFT') return 'ArrowLeft';
    if (state === 'UP') return 'ArrowUp';
    if (state === 'RIGHT') return 'ArrowRight';
    if (state === 'DOWN') return 'ArrowDown';
    if (state === 'LEFTUP') return ['ArrowLeft', 'ArrowUp'];
    if (state === 'LEFTDOWN') return ['ArrowLeft', 'ArrowDown'];
    if (state === 'RIGHTUP') return ['ArrowRight', 'ArrowUp'];
    if (state === 'RIGHTDOWN') return ['ArrowRight', 'ArrowDown'];
    return false;
}
AStarWalk(path) {
    for (let i in path) {
        let key = this.AStarGetKey(path[i]);
        if (!key) break;
        // How to simulate the keypress per key which works with keydown ?
        document.getElementById('gameWindow').dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'code': key}));
    }
}
```

}

Sorry for my English guys, is not my native language. I hope you will find the power to understand me ;-)

Comment: Why isn't it possible to just call `this.engine.player.movePlayer(1);` when the AStar says "left"? Do you need this to happen with a delay for the next key?

Comment: Do you really need to simulate a keypress instead of just calling into the game logic itself?

Comment: @Adder I thought about it, But I prefer to simulate the keypress.
Because in the future there will be some changes to the code and I prefer to solve it now and it will be more readable for me.
There should be a delay until the animation finish before it simulates the next key. In the character class which runs the animation, there is a status variable that contains boolean if the animation is running or not and the delay should be based on that.

Comment: Well, how about putting the path into an array with user actions, and consuming that array from the front (FIFO) while appending to the end.